# How can I create a new dataframe with the products of another dataframe which has been grouped?

Tags: python-3.x, dataframe

Input:

```
dfB=dfA.groupby('labelA').labelB.nlargest(3)
```

Output:

```
labelA      
G       5309   415004880.00
        6016   268492764.00
        5570   191452396.00
PG      6687   486295561.00
        5943   400738009.00
        5987   368061265.00
PG-13   6380   936662225.00
        6391   652270625.00
        5723   623357910.00
R       6616   363070709.00
        6184   350126372.00
        5569   254464305.00
Name: labelB, dtype: float64
```

I now would like to create a new data frame, to which I can visualise, containing the mean of each group(G, PG, PG-13, R). I tried the following, however, as shown below, the output is the mean of all 4 groups combined.

Input:

```
barB.mean()
```

Output:

```
442499751.75
```

Answer (score 0):

```
dfB = dfA.groupby('labelA').labelB.apply(lambda x: x.nlargest(3).mean())
```

You can use `apply` to chain the mean-function to nlargest.